# How do I access a variable in the constructor from a custom toString method?

Tags: java, tostring

In my example, I am having a hard time figuring out how to return the characters from the CreditCard constructor in to the toString.

`char c` in the constructor will be used to accomplish the instructions below, but I can't access it in `toString()` for some reason. Why is this?

```
//Write a class that represents a credit card. Call this class CreditCard.          
//The class will have the following fields and methods:
//A constructor which takes a String to set the card number. 
//Ignore dashes,spaces, and any other non-digit characters.
//A public method called toString that returns the credit card number.

public class CreditCard 
{
public CreditCard(String cardNumber)
{ 
        char c = 0;
        for( int i=0; i<cardNumber.length(); i++)
        {
            c = cardNumber.charAt(i);

            if(Character.isDigit(c))
            {
                System.out.print(c);
            }      
        }

}
public String toString() //toString method
{

        return c;
}

}//end code
```

Comment: Umm I believe using the set/get methods should do that, if I am reading your question correctly.

Comment: you just need to override your toString with your data field which u do not have any. **do you know the usage of toString?**

Comment: BTW: `c.toString()` will give you the string representation of c, but again I think using the mutator methods will be more beneficial

Comment: @ryekayo how toString will see the c here?

Answer (score 2):

There are three types of variables in java (in common use):

- **Local Variables** are declared within constructors and methods and are only available within those constructors and methods. `char c` from your example is one such local variable, and can only be accessed within the constructor.
- **Instance Variables** are declared outside the constructors and methods but inside the class. They are available to all methods and constructors for a given instance of a class. In your case - a given credit card.
- **Static Variables** are declared in the same way as instance variables but have the `static` tag. These are available to the methods and constructors of *every* instance of a class. In your case, a static variable is available to all credit cards you create.

You need to make use of instance variables so that you can transfer the credit card number from the constructor to the toString method.

```
public class CreditCard {
    String cardNumber = ""; // <-- This is an instance variable
    public CreditCard(String constructorInput) { // <-- Constructor input has the number as well as special characters, but it's just a local variable
        // Remove special characters (dashes and spaces) from
        // constructorInput here, and put the remaining numbers
        // in the instance variable - cardNumber.
    }

    @Override // <-- See the answers below for why I have this
    public String toString() {
        return cardNumber; // <-- Both the constructor and toString can access cardNumber, so just output it.
    }
}
```

Further reading: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_variable_types.htm

Answer (score 0):

Keep a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) field, [`append`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append-char-) to it the characters and `return` its' [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#toString--) (and I would personally prefer a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) on the [`String.toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--)). Something like

```
public class CreditCard {
    // To store the digit(s) of the CreditCard String.
    private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // To construct a CreditCard instance.
    public CreditCard(String cardNumber) {
        // for-each char c in the character array backing
        // cardNumber.
        for (char c : cardNumber.toCharArray()) {
            // Test that the current character is a digit, 
            if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                // It is, append it to the StringBuilder.
                sb.append(c);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // Call toString() on the StringBuilder.
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Also, it's a good idea to take advantage of the [`Override` annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) per [JLS-9.6.3.4 `@Override`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.3.4) which says (in part) *Programmers occasionally overload a method declaration when they mean to override it* ... ***If a method declaration is annotated with the annotation `@Override`, but the method does not override or implement a method declared in a supertype, or is not override-equivalent to a `public` method of `Object`, a compile-time error occurs.***

Comment: I really do not get it when the op **does not know the fundamentals** why you  posted such an answer?

Comment: Override is a good annotation and the link is relevant, but briefly summarizing what it does is helpful :)

Comment: @KickButtowski It can be difficult to learn to the *fundamentals*, especially when you are first starting out. That is why I provided Javadocs and (IMO) the above is fairly fundamental.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I totally understand ur point, but if it is the case, why do not you flag this question as too broad or something else.

Comment: @KickButtowski Learning fundamentals from a SO question is perfectly okay... it is not "too broad" as long as it focuses on a specific fundamental.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I didn't mean that the link was unclear, I only meant that OP's level of knowledge in programming might not be to the level of reading javadocs - they can be very technical and unhelpful. Breaking the concepts down into simplest terms is useful to everyone.